# Screen-Keypad off for samsung device

Tags: java, mobile, java-me, nokia, samsung-mobile

I am developing a game in j2me. How to off the screen-keypad for Samsung device. I used SGH-M8800 emulator.

I find solution for Nokia
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Using_on-screen_keypad_in_MIDlets_in_S60_5th_Edition_devices

How to make for Samsung device ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add the following property on .jad file,

```
// Nokia/SE:
Nokia-MIDlet-On-Screen-Keypad: no

// Samsung?
Navi-Key-Hidden: true
MIDlet-Touch-Support: true
```

Comment: Navi-key-Hidden its not working .. I find this solution      <attribute name="MIDlet-Touch-Support" value="true"/>          
<attribute name="ATT-MIDlet-VirtualKeypad-Use" value="No"/>

Comment: Its working only for samsung device. Any solution for LG touch ?

Comment: Based on this [discussion](http://www.j2meforums.com/forum/index.php?action=printpage;topic=21421.0), It should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using JAVA phone and you're facing 4 keys on your java game...don't be afraid i have an solution ....
First you need to install "Minicommander"
http://boostapps.com/files/MiniCommndr.jar
Here is link ^^^^^^
After installation minicommander just open the Game setup through minicommander And then META-INF ->MANIFEST.MF & then click 4 and press Ok And midest of the passage juat type this code "MIDlet-Touch-Support: true"
And press OK & SAVE File .....
And go back to your memory card and install this game again .... and launch the game the you wil find there's no Extra keypad on your game...i promise it's totally working...